# How would I extract row information based on a value on a column in Excel or Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

I'm building an excel spreadsheet for a project I'm working on and I'm running into an issue relaying the data.

If I have data like so:
**Name** **Info1** **Info2** **Condition1** **Condition2**
foo1      3        9        X
foo2      8       10                               X
foo3      2        7        X                      X

I have an formula that, based on certain conditions, generates a "condition" flag. I then want to develop a way on another sheet, pull from this data set all the lines that contain the "Condition".

Example: Cell generates Condition1, display all the rows and values that have an "X" in the column "Condition1".

I know I can use filters but this isn't going to be custom-facing data. If filters are the only way, is there a script that can be done to auto-filter based on the value of a cell so the user doesn't see the other data (unless they manually edit the filter)?

I've tried VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP combinations as well as INDEX and dabbled in MATCH. The issue I'm having is if I have 40 items that match Condition1 and then the next day it auto-switches to Condition2 and it has 10 items, I'm finding difficulty in writing a script to generate all of those items.

Comment: VBA and Google Apps Script are very different approaches - so if you're going to script this, take your pick between Excel or Sheets (but not both).

Comment: That said, maybe `FILTER` would be useful here.

Comment: Right now I'm writing this in Google Apps mainly for the convenience of sharing the file with others but if it can only be done in Excel, I can cross input the data I have so far with no issues.

Comment: FILTER IS starting to do what I want! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Sheets or Excel 365 then you can use `FILTER()`.  If your version of Excel supports the `AGGREGATE()` function, then it can be used.  If you are using a Jurassic version of Excel, then you can use `MATCH()` to retrieve the data you require.  Say we have:

[image]

and we want records where *cond1* has an *x*.  Namely rows 2, 4, 7, 11, 13, 17, and 19.

In **G1** enter:

```
=MATCH("x",D:D,0)
```

In **G2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("x",INDEX(D:D,G1+1):INDEX(D:D,9999),0)+G1,"")
```

and copy downward.  Each `MATCH()` formula examines a separate chunk of column **D**:

[image]

The `MATCH()` formula in **G1** starts at the top of column **D**, the `MATCH()` formula in **G2** starts one cell below the match found in **G1**, etc. Once we have the row numbers, `INDEX()` can be used to retrieve any info on that row.